# How did Extranonce2_size change?

Tags: mining-pools, stratum

From stratum,I know that the coinbase is composed of "Coinb1 +Extranonce1 + Extranonce2 + Coinb2".

How did Extranonce2_size change ?

Will the Extranonce2_size change when I connect to a pool?

Answer (score 1):

Miner sent message mining.subscribe to pool

```
mining.subscribe("user agent/version", "extranonce1")
```

Pool reply with

```
[[["mining.set_difficulty", "subscription id 1"],
["mining.notify", "subscription id 2"]],
"extranonce1",
extranonce2_size]
```

Pool set size of extranonce2

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I would like to know in what situation the Extranonce2_size will be changed.